# How do I join two tables where the result gives me multiple results for some, but I only want one

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join

I have two tables: **tng_people** and **tng_events** in my genealogy database.

**tng_people** stores the basic information about each person, each person having a unique **personID**.
**tng_events** stores events that are linked to a person, some people don't have an event linked to them, others might have several events (lines in the database) linked to them. The only event I am interested in is cause of death (varible **tng_events.cause**).

That is; I want a list of people (*firstname*, *lastname*) that have drowned (*burialplace LIKE "%votri%"*), and IF they have a cause of death listed, I want to display that cause in the last column.

If I run just the basic query

```
SELECT tng_people.firstname, tng_people.lastname FROM tng_people
WHERE (burialplace LIKE "%votri%");
```

I get 345 individuals. I want to also get 345 individuals after doing the **JOIN**, but I get 581 - because of the additional empty lines that get added due to a person having more than one event linked to them.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT tng_people.firstname, tng_people.lastname, tng_events.cause FROM tng_people
JOIN tng_events ON tng_people.personID = tng_events.persfamID
WHERE (burialplace LIKE "%votri%");
```

I can't say that I only want to get lines where **tng_events.cause** is not NULL, because not all individuals have a cause of death listed.

I have tried all the different **JOIN** methods, none give me the correct results, so I am beginning to believe this is not connected to that.

I hope I have explained this well enough! If not, please let me know.
Rakel

EDIT:
I have just noticed that there is an additional column **tng_events.parenttag** which has the value **DEAT**, if there is a cause of death listed.

I added that to my query so it now looks like this:

```
 SELECT tng_people.firstname, tng_people.lastname, tng_events.cause FROM tng_people 
JOIN tng_events ON tng_people.personID = tng_events.persfamID 
WHERE (burialplace LIKE "%votri%") AND tng_events.parenttag="DEAT";
```

But now the problem has just reversed, now I just get the ones that have cause of death listed, so my list is cut down to 222 (instead of the 345). That is because not all on my list have a cause of death (as I mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

### Almost had it...

You need to make the `tng_events.parenttag="DEAT"` predicate part of the `JOIN` condition, so that the events table only joins when it's that type of event. You also need to use an `OUTER JOIN` such as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so it doesn't remove any people records that don't match. (The `JOIN` keyword by itself is shorthand for [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/joins.php) which only returns matching rows.) Assuming that every person can only have 1 death event, this shouldn't duplicate your data:

```
SELECT tng_people.firstname, tng_people.lastname, tng_events.cause 
FROM tng_people 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tng_events 
    ON tng_people.personID = tng_events.persfamID 
    AND tng_events.parenttag="DEAT"
WHERE (burialplace LIKE "%votri%");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  p.firstname, p.lastname,
        GROUP_CONCAT(e.cause)       -- Note
    FROM  tng_people AS p
    JOIN  tng_events AS e  ON p.personID = e.persfamID
    WHERE  p.burialplace LIKE "%votri%"
      AND  e.parenttag="DEAT"       -- Which table is this in??
    GROUP BY e.persfamID;           -- Note
```

(I did not follow your comment about "blank".)

If you want output for people with no entry in `events`, then JD's `LEFT JOIN` may be closer to correct.